# sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable shows wrong row counts when we use growing on

Tags: sapui5

When I set the `growing="true"` the smarttable shows wrong number of rows. How can I fix it?

[image]

In the [documentations](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/methods/setShowRowCount) it says:

> To avoid sending dedicated OData requests in order to improve your application's performance, you must configure the binding of the table as required.

It seems by configuring the binding of the smarttable this problem is solvable! but how I can play with this configuration? Can anyone provide me an example?

Comment: can you check the property "growingThreshold='4'" , A working example here "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrowing/code". 


Also, oData should also be implemented for $top, $skip etc.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi The oData supports $top and $skip as I can load the data page by page. It has growing threshold 20! It double the number of loaded data. as it is 20 it shows 40, 80, 160, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer regarding this issue.

I discovered what it shows as the row count is the number that the following function returns:

```
oTable.getBinding("items").getLength()
```

`oTable` is the inner table inside the smart table.

But in reality what must be shown is the number of current context.

So if you bind the header of the smart table to a property in your view model you can update it each time the inner table is updated.

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="__smartTableWorklist0" header="{woklistView>/table0}" showRowCount="false" tableType="ResponsiveTable" .....>                                    
    <Table id="table0" growing="true" growingThreshold="50" updateFinished="onTableUpdateFinished"> ... </Table>
```

And in the controller you have to update the header property like the following:

```
onTableUpdateFinished: function (oEvent) {
    var oViewModel = this.getModel("woklistView");
    var oTable = this.byId("table0");
    oViewModel.setProperty("/table0", "Some Title (" + oTable.getBinding("items").getCurrentContexts().length + ")");
},
```